# Adding GDA2020 NTv2 transformation to ArcGIS 10.5

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-10.5, geoid, gda2020, ntv2-transformation

The implementation of GDA2020 is drawing near! In an effort to be ready before time I have downloaded the NTv2 Grid Shift Binary (GSB) transformation grid from ISCM (available [here](https://github.com/icsm-au/transformation_grids)) who are the *official* custodians of all things GDA2020 related. I am using the `GDA94_GDA2020_conformal_and_distortion.gsb` as well as AUSGeoid2020 (available [here](http://www.ga.gov.au/scientific-topics/positioning-navigation/geodesy/ahdgm/ausgeoid2020)).

ArcGIS 10.5 does have GDA2020/MGA2020 in the list of available coordinate systems.. a good start. ArcGIS 10.2 does not recognize GDA2020 calling the CRS "custom" but locating correctly.

When transforming from GDA94 to GDA2020 ArcGIS has a default transformation GDA_1994_To_GDA2020_1 which doesn't match a GSB file in the `australia` folder but may be a parameter only transformation. I am uncertain as to the accuracy of this transformation and so followed the instructions in [this Esri support post about installing a new NTv2 file](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010151) attempting to install the downloaded GSB file as the *assumed to be more correct* transformation between these datums.

Has anyone verified that the default Esri transformation is close enough (4th decimal place in MGA2020) to the ISCM GSB *for all of Australia* so that I don't need to jump through all these hoops on *every* workstation with ArcGIS installed?

Note: I understand that this isn't much of a question; I have posted this mostly as a resource for users who will be implementing GDA2020 after frustrating hours encountering numerous broken links and reading through verbose documents in a quest for a correct transformation and I'm hoping that this vague question saves others a considerable amount of time and frustration by posting the working links... at least until the data moves again and these links become broken too.

Comment: Is it an option for you to upgrade to 10.6?  Esri Australia seems to be saying that it "just works" there: https://esriaustraliatechblog.wordpress.com/2018/01/04/gda2020-arcgis/

Comment: I'd like to know if the pre-packaged transformation is a parameterized or NTv2. Working with datum transformation isn't something that I have done before so I'm unsure how to prove/disprove the existing transformation. *"Just works"* makes me cringe, I'm concerned about processing months worth of data and then having rejected by a client because the shift isn't correct.. considering the development of GDA2020 has been in progress for a significant amount of time if Esri adopted an earlier model released by ISCM there could be problems. Perhaps it's something I should contact Esri support on.

Comment: I would definitely contact them.  Also, if [mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/963/mkennedy?tab=profile) looks in on this and answers/comments I would take that as gospel.

Comment: The link PolyGeo posted states 10.6 / 2.1 only supports the parameter transform out of the box, unless you manually install the grids (includes instructions).