# QGIS Australia GDA94 to 2020 Transformation File (NTv2_3>

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, australia, transform, gda2020

I'm looking to convert some Australian GIS data from GDA 94 to 2020. The reprojection exists, but I need to use a particular transformation - specially NT v2_3 Conformal (this exists in ESRI). I believe I need a file and save into a particularly folder, but I don't know how to obtain this file.

How can I?

Comment: See my question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/301111/adding-gda2020-ntv2-transformation-to-arcgis-10-5 for the link to locate the transformation from ICSM and following adding a new NTv2 to Esri. It is uncertain if you mean desktop or pro but the link should help.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Title references QGIS even though the body mentions the fact that the transformation is available in Esri.

Comment: @mkennedy the question is about obtaining the conformal NTv2 transformation file. Even though the linked question is about Esri it contains the link to the ICSM where the file can be obtained.